# Running 3/4" conduit (sch-40) partially inside 2x4 wall

Tags: conduit

Any thoughts or rules regarding drilling 1-1/8" holes in middle of 2x4's ? Also planning to drill thru double-stud (two 2x4 sandwiched) that support a double 2x8(w/plywood ctr) beam(9'long). I could possibly drill thru lower half of double wall plate instead but that would locally eliminate the lower plate under that same beam. Appreciate reply. Yes Sch-40 3/4 because fill exceeds 40% of 1/2 .. with ground wire. Sounds like 1/2" EMT could work and be the ground. Just not a fan of "conductive" conduit.

Comment: Are you using 3/4 pipe ( sch 40) or conduit ( Not sch 40 ) ?

Comment: @blacksmith37 probably intending PVC, which is Sch 40 or Sch 80. Rigid or IMC are the same OD as pipe of the same nominal size. EMT is smaller.

Comment: EMT is thinner walls, and has a couple of advantages, notably isn't glued so it's easy to disassemble for rework.  You can also transition from EMT to PVC at any point just with an EMT connector and PVC female threaded coupling.

Comment: Thanks for replies & info .. after checking sizes of EMTs it occurred to me that I calculated the 1/2" sch-40 area with a .25r but it had .622 ID. So, 3 8awg THHN will fill to 35% vs 54%. Now my hole size is .875 :).

Comment: I see the ID fir 1/2" EMT is the same as Sch-4 (.622) and OD is leas than 3/4" .. a lesser drill size. If I can use this just for the in wall section and then convert to Sch-40 where it is exposed to weather (under porch and in garage). Any concerns with HTTN wire getting abraded ? Especially if EMT gets corroded ? I'd obviously need a ground wire. What fitting(s) would tanke me from 1/2 EMT to 1/2 Sch-40 ? Doubt I can bend "in place" so, still skeptical. I could make one S ahead of time and insert straight pieces after IF I have precision-located holes. ??

Answer (score 6):

The rule [IRC R602.6.2](https://codes.iccsafe.org/s/IRC2018P4/chapter-6-wall-construction/IRC2018P4-Ch06-SecR602.6) is less than 60% (or 40% for exterior/bearing - between 40 & 60% in those walls, you have to double the studs and can only have 2 such doubled/bored studs in a row) and not closer than 5/8" to the edge.

Your holes would be 35% of actual stud width. If centered, 1-1/8" from the edge.

You could use 3/4" EMT, which has an actual OD under an inch, rather than PVC or rigid, which is over an inch.

Comment: And the 3/4" EMT saves you a ground wire.

Comment: Assuming, @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact, that it's properly grounded at both ends. ;)

Comment: @FreeMan Which is easy if you use metal boxes everywhere.

Comment: Indeed. However, there's no indication that the OP is doing so. For many DIYers, metal boxes are scary until the benefits are learned. I certainly thought so at first. I've since learned different. ;)

Comment: I tend to be a bit paranoid about relying on metal conduit as ground path. I can visualize some future owner not understanding this, replacing a section with NMC without re-grounding the conduit, and getting themselves in trouble. I've also just never 100% trusted that the conduit connections won't corrode or loose and increase resistance.I do have places in my house where that's the only way to get ground, but I tend to put in GFCIs when I notice those; belt, suspenders, and helium balloons.

Comment: As I've linked before on the subject: https://www.nema.org/docs/default-source/technical-document-library/steel-conduit-and-emt-proven-to-meet-the-nec-reg.pdf